# Jquery .remove() only acts on second click and after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap popover that pops up after clicking on a notification icon on my page. Part of its functionality is to remove any notification from the popover after clicking on it. Here is an image of the popover with three notifications, for reference:

[notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRjYN.png)

However, when I open the notification popover, then click on any of the notifications, the first click won't remove the notification, but the second one will. The click listener is firing both the first and second times (confirmed with logging to console). I checked other questions similar to mine, but none of them had a solution that worked for me. I read up on something about the "focus" but couldn't understand what they meant. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Here is the popover code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#notificationsBell").popover({
    'title' : $('.notifications-title-header').html(), // display:none so it doesn't show up in window
    'html' : true,
    'placement' : 'left',
    'content' : $(".notifications-list").html() // display:none
  });
});
```

And here is the click listener that is supposed to remove the notification:

```js
$('body').off("click").on("click", ".popover-body .notif-popup-container", function() {
  var notifId = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#' + notifId).remove();
})
```

I think it has to do with the popover and display:none aspects. This is because I try removing elements elsewhere in the code without display:none and the popover, and it works on the first click. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Can you replace `off()` by `unbind()` and check? I assume it because on older jquery version.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the notification-only you clicked upon ?, and could you place some html code, some [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to work upon..??

Answer (score 1):

If the element you're adding a click event listener to. doesn't exist yet that could be a problem.

What's `.off` btw

Comment: It definitely exists since the print statement inside the click listener prints both times. .off is meant to de-register the click listener so there's not multiple on a page for the same element.

Comment: Are you sure you're clicking on it and not something else. I'm gonna need a reproducible example to be able to help.